# Automatic daily reset counter to a time using flipclock.js

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, flipclock

I am trying to implement a countdown timer that will countdown to 8AM of everyday. That is if visited today after 8AM, it countdowns to tomorrow's 8AM and if visited today before 8AM, it countdowns to today's 8AM. I'm using flipclock.js (http://www.flipclockjs.com). I'm looking for a javascript only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still trying to achieve this? Please see my post as I have currently got this working, but I need a few modifications i.e excluding the weekends and daylight saving changes.

[Daily Timer to Exempt Days and Allow for DST in UK - FlipClock.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657570/daily-timer-to-exempt-days-and-allow-for-dst-in-uk-flipclock-js)